# Visual Studio: How to turn off "String Defination" popup/tooltip

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I have updated Visual Studio on my Mac system a few months ago and having some annoying large "String Defination" popup when i try to select any string. These are really annoying and i have to wait for them to disappear and continue my work. Is there any solution to turn off these popups. Although it is not programming or logic related question but these popups are really annoying and waste a reasonable time druing development. So any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Also I know that it is not good to attach picture here but I think it will clear my question.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Ahh. . . . At last I found a solution.
Although steps are simple but it is strange that no-one has replied me yet since 11 days passed to the question. . . anyway

Go to Visual Studio

- Preferences
- then select text editor tab
- Select Behaviour
- Then select c#
- Un-Check the option "Show remarks in quick info"
  Thats it.

These popup/tooltips were really annoying, I am happy to found a way to stop displaying them. . .